# Append n columns together

Tags: awk, cut

I have a large dataset, which shows how variable y changes as a function of both space (x) and time (t). There are n columns, each representing one time step. They are tab delimited.

note: there are no headers in the actual text file, they are just added here for explanation. Nor should there be headers in the output.

```
x   y(0)   y(1)    y(2)    y(3) ... y(n)
1   4      4.5     5       5.5  ... 100
2   5      5.5     6       6.5  ... 101
3   7      8       9       10   ... 102
4   10     12      14      16   ... 103
```

I need to reorganise my file so that I have only 3 columns; t, x, y, which should be sorted in that order, as below.

```
0 1 4
0 2 5
0 3 7
0 4 10
1 1 4.5
1 2 5.5
1 3 8
1 4 12
2 1 5
2 2 6
2 3 9
2 4 14
3 1 5.5
3 2 6.5
3 3 10
3 4 16
etc
```

Any help much appreciated. I feel like this should be possible using awk, but any solution is fine.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '{
         k=NR; x[k]=$1;
         for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
             t[i-1][k]=$i 
     }
     END{
         for (i in t) 
             for (j in t[i]) 
                 print i-1, x[j], t[i][j] 
     }' file
```

- `k=NR` - crucial key reflecting *function* *`y`* axis value (`NR` - record number)
- `x[k]=$1` - capture value for axis `x`
- `for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)` - iterating though fields starting from the 2nd

  - `t[i-1][k]=$i` - fill up the *time axis* array `t` with *function* `y` values

---

The output:

```
0 1 4
0 2 5
0 3 7
0 4 10
1 1 4.5
1 2 5.5
1 3 8
1 4 12
2 1 5
2 2 6
2 3 9
2 4 14
3 1 5.5
3 2 6.5
3 3 10
3 4 16
...
```

Comment: A good solution, although I did mention that there are no headers in the actual file, and this answer assumes that there are. Perhaps I didn't make this clear enough, since every other answer assumed the same.

Nor should there be headers in the output.

Comment: If you could update the answer how you recommend that would be very useful.

Comment: @L.Marsden, see my update

Comment: I receive an error when I try to run this solution. Any idea what the problem is? I have tried to run this code on my actual dataset and also my example dataset. 

awk: cmd. line:3:              t[i-1][k]=$i
awk: cmd. line:3:                    ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:7:              for (j in t[i])
awk: cmd. line:7:                         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:8:                  print i-1, x[j], t[i][j]
awk: cmd. line:8:                                       ^ syntax error

Comment: @L.Marsden, its yours. The solution works fine and here's a screenshot https://ibb.co/fQZQeR. That's all

Comment: I see that it works on your PC. I have replicated the job flow and receive that error message. What could be the problem? I have simply copied and pasted your code into my text editor, changed 'file' to my file name, and then executed the script.

Comment: @L.Marsden, show the output of this two: 1) `lsb_release -a` ; 2) `awk --version`

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7, base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:grap                                                  hics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind looping over the input `n` times:

```
n=4   ### your N here
for((t=0; t <= n)); t++))
do 
  awk -F$'\t' -v t=$t '{print t, $1, $(t+2)}' < input
done > output
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative GNU **`datamash`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
datamash -W transpose <filename \
| awk 'NR==1{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) x[i]=$i }
       NR > 1{
           for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NR-2, x[i], $i 
       }'
```

The output:

```
0 1 4
0 2 5
0 3 7
0 4 10
1 1 4.5
1 2 5.5
1 3 8
1 4 12
2 1 5
2 2 6
2 3 9
2 4 14
3 1 5.5
3 2 6.5
3 3 10
3 4 16
```

Comment: @L.Marsden, the answer is updated to omit header line/column